# Exponential decaying sine fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am trying to fit a decaying sine signal over time to calculate tau (signal * 1/e), but I don't know how to do this. I have a CSV file with 2^16 data points, so it's hard to create an useful MWE. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work well since it's not really a function to analyze. Only the left decaying part is relevant; the right part doesn't matter.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def find_peaks(x, y):
    peak_x = []
    peak_vals = []
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        if i == len(y) - 1:
            continue
        if (y[i-1] < y[i]) and (y[i+1] < y[i]):
            peak_x.append(x[i])
            peak_vals.append(y[i])
    return np.array(peak_x), np.array(peak_vals)


file_path = 'data.dat'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t')
t = df.values[0:,0]
sig = df.values[0:,1]

x, y = find_peaks(t, sig)

plt.plot(t,sig)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Here is a plot of my data:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work well"?

Comment: The orange fit line has some "ripples". I need a "normal" exponential decaying fit

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "normal" here.  You haven't done any fitting at all.  All you've done is extracted the peaks.  Are you looking for a function to describe this curve?  Are you looking for a single decay factor?

Comment: Yeah, I want a function which describes the orange line as a exponential decay like e^(-bx). My goal is to calculate the time constant of this dynamical system... (it's a signal over time)